# Understanding namespace scope in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope

When I run this below code snippet, the output is **a is 6**. But since I have used namespace n1, which also has variable by name "a", shouldn't the output be **a is 5**. Am I missing something ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace n1{
    int a = 5;
}

int main(void){
    int a = 6;
    using namespace n1;
    cout<<"a is "<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But if I use fully qualified name in cout i.e cout<<"a is "<<**n1::a**; the output is as expected i.e. 5. What is the purpose of **using namespace** ?

Comment: your `a` is the local of main. you have to use `n1::a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is simple:
***"Local variables always shadow/hide the variables in other namespaces or global variables with same name."***

Within the scope in which local variable `a` is declared, the using directive has no effect w.r.t the symbol name `a`. It still does import all the symbol names from namespace `n1` within the current scope but the local variable `a` still hides `n1::a`. So `n1::a` is simply not visible and you need to use the fully qualified name for it.

Comment: But if I define variable a globally instead of locally(but still keeping namespace definition), the compiler reports 'a' to be ambiguous symbol. So is that namespace or globally defined variables do not get preference over each other ?

Comment: @niting112: Only local variables are treated special in this regard. As you noticed in case of namespace variables and global neither is given the special treatment and hence the ambiguity error.

Answer (score 5):

The `using` directive is a hint to the compiler for places where it should search the name `a`.

This way, the name look-up will be done in this order:

- First search for `a` in the local scope
- If `a` isn't found, search in the namespace `n1`
- If there's still no `a` found, look in the global namespace

Without the `using` directive you provided, the second step wouldn't be performed.

In your case, as there is actually a variable (but it could be anything, we're talking about *names*) named `a`, it doesn't go any further.

Comment: But if a is defined as global instead of local and is also defined in namespace, compiler marks it error saying "a is ambiguous". But according to above rule, shouldn't variable a defined in namespace should take precendence above global scope "

Comment: Uh ? When I try a very simple example, I have no such message... (declaring and defining `a` as a global, in a namespace, and in the main scope).

Comment: May be this is compiler dependent. I am using visual studio 2010. Which one you tested on ?

Comment: This code compiles, runs and behaves as expected with win32-msvc2012.

Answer (score 1):

when a variable is defined in the local namespace (a in main is in your local namespace) it will prefer it.

So in this case you must tell it (I  would like the a from the n1 namespace n1::a)
if you remove the a it will work as expected...